# Blackwell-Rao applications to Machine Learning and AI

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

We learned recently in a graduate statistic course about Blackwell-Rao of an unbiased estimator statistic T; other methods for parameter estimation includes Maximum Likelihood and Method of Moments and we studied their asymptotic behavior for consistent estimators.

Q: Are there any recommendations of papers in the field of Machine Learning and AI where one can read applications of for instance Blackwell-Rao used in an interesting way? For instance there were some suggestions on Blackwell-Rao applied in particle filtering for dynamic Bayesian networks. Looking for accessible papers to read for math graduate students who have recently taken a course in statistics, with some background in programming/cs.

PS: Is this the wrong forum to ask such question? If so, please suggest where I could probably direct this question.